# How to create a MainLayout for refreshing the current page using Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, page-refresh

My MainLayout contains a horizontal menu as well as a button on the top of the screen. The button brings up a modal for the user to make a selection. After it closes I need the current page to refresh because their selection affects key state which affects all pages.

I am calling this.StateHasChanged(); in the MainLayout page. This does cause its content to refresh. However, it does not cause the content of the page contained in the @Body to refresh. I have looked quite a bit and don't see how to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either pass the values down via a CascadingValue, because that will cause consumers to render when the value changes - or if you are relying on state external to the components (such as in a service) then you'll need to put an event on there that is triggered when your state changes, and your consuming components will have to subscribe and call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`